# Trying to import/convert a CRA app into Razzle JS

Tags: reactjs, webpack, sass, create-react-app, razzle

I'm new to Razzle and I'm trying to learn it.  I took a [Material-UI dashboard app](https://github.com/devias-io/react-material-dashboard) and am trying to "import" or "convert" it into my blank-ish razzle app.

I copied the contents of the CRA app's `./src` into my razzle source at the right spot, referenced the right components, etc.

At first, Razzle didn't like the `@import` statements in the CRA repo.  I fixed that by using npm to install `razzle-plugin-scss`, which got me past that issue.  But now I'm hitting something I don't understand at all (nor even how to go about finding a resolution):

```
{ Error: Cannot find module 'css-loader/locals'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:649:15)
    at Function.resolve (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:19:19)
    at module.exports (/home/user/my-project/node_modules/razzle-plugin-scss/index.js:106:31)
    at runPlugin (/home/user/my-project/node_modules/razzle/config/runPlugin.js:26:10)
    at plugins.forEach.plugin (/home/user/my-project/node_modules/razzle/config/createConfig.js:549:16)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at module.exports (/home/user/my-project/node_modules/razzle/config/createConfig.js:548:13)
    at main (/home/user/my-project/node_modules/razzle/scripts/start.js:48:22)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/next_tick.js:81:5) code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
```

I looked in `css-loader` and found that you (maybe?) need to instruct it to export locals with the `exportOnlyLocals: true` webpack directive.  I'm not sure how to do that in Razzle.  I found [this page](https://github.com/jaredpalmer/razzle/tree/master/packages/razzle-plugin-scss) that shows an example of how to configure it through `razzle.config.js`, but it assumes more knowledge than I have.

How can I configure webpack in Razzle to ... do something? ... to tell the underlying webpack plugin `css-loader` to load locals?

Any help is much appreciated.

**Update**

It looks like this is caused by a breaking change in `css-loader` when it moved to `v2.0.0`.  I still don't know what the solution is, but that's getting me closer.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up reverting to `css-loader` version `1.0.1` to fix the problem.